# Why do I keep receiving an inputmismatchexception on my array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been running through this array of objects trying to figure out what I am doing wrong and I can't see the error. This program runs through the first iteration bringing in Austria and all its subsequent information but will not move onto the second part of the array. I thought it might be that it's somehow taking each variable from the countries class and making it its own spot in the array but that can't be it because I have increased the array size to 64 and it still stops at the end of Austria. I have been able to get it to go a bit further by placing print statements after each item is added and it seems to be adding an unaccounted for blank line in it for some reason and I'm not sure why. any help that could be given would be greatly appreciated.

This is my test code with the data list:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Test  {
   public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
      final String INPUT_FILE = "CountriesInfo2.txt";

      FileReader inputDataFile = new FileReader (INPUT_FILE);
      Scanner read = new Scanner (inputDataFile);
      Countries[] c = new Countries[8];

      for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
         c[i] = new Countries();
         c[i].countryName = read.nextLine();
         c[i].latitude = read.nextLine();
         c[i].longitude = read.nextLine();
         c[i].countryArea = read.nextInt();
         c[i].countryPopulation = read.nextInt();
         c[i].countryGDP = read.nextDouble();
         c[i].countryYear = read.nextInt();
         sop ("" + c[i].countryName + "\n" + c[i].latitude+"\n"+c[i].longitude+"\n"+c[i].countryArea+"\n"+
         c[i].countryPopulation+"\n"+c[i].countryGDP+"\n"+c[i].countryYear);
      }// end for
   } // End Main
   public static void sop (String s) {
      System.out.println(s);
   } // End sop
} // end class
```

Austria
47 20 N
13 20 E
83871 8754513 417.2 2016
Belgium
50 50 N
04 00 E
30528 11491346 509.5 2016
Czech Republic
49 45 N
15 30 E
7886
10674723
350.7
2016
France
46 00 N
02 00 E
643801
67106161
2734.0
2016

This list is supposed to be one line for each bit of information with lat-long having 2 sets of double digits and a letter each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nextLine() automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line. Rather I would advise you do as following

1. read each line using `String data = scanner.nextLine();`
2. split the data using space separator `String[] pieces =
   data.split("\\s+");`
3. set the pieces to Country attributes by converting them in to
   their appropriate type.

   eg.   `c[i].countryName = pieces[0];`

   ```
      `c[i].latitude = piece[1];`
   ```

Comment: I cant use the space separator due to there being countries such as the Czech Republic in the list mixed with single name countries such as Austria And the Lat-Long coordinates require 3 separate sections each. 
Can you explain more about what you mean with the converting to appropriate type?

Comment: I see. why don't separate them with comma and use comma separator instead like `data.split(",")`. When I meant by to change to appropriate type:  since all the elements in the array are strings, you can use like  `Integer.parseInt("Stringinput")` or `Double.parseDouble("stringinput")` to convert them to their appropriate attribute type.

Comment: Good idea! I'll give that a shot.